# Hiding a button with multiple windows? - Objective C OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, window, hide

I have an application which has a button on the first window, once pressed this button should hide and perform an action, to hide the button i'm using this code:

```
[self.myButton setHidden:TRUE];
```

This works fine until I have multiple windows - new instances of this window do not have this button it's hidden by default. However when I create a new window and press the myButton on the first window it doesn't hide the button.

Furthermore if I create a new window and then close that window and press the myButton on the first and now only window it crashes.

Any ideas how to overcome this?

Comment: Please add any relevant code to creating the windows, etc.

Comment: Hey it's just calling a newDocument from the document controller:

[dc newDocument:self];

Answer (score 0):

myButton is pointing to the button in the last window you opened